# How to find the mean and standard deviation of all numerical variables in a SAS dataset

Tags: arrays, sas, statistics, sas-macro

Here's the question I'm working with:

Write a single DATA step that takes an existing SAS data set and creates a new SAS data
set for which each observation consists of the mean and standard deviation of the absolute values of all
numeric variables in the corresponding observation from the original set. (Note: the new data set should
have the same number of observations as the old data set, but only two variables.) Use arrays with the
functions MEAN, STD, and ABS for the numerical calculations. Your code should employ macro
variables so that it works for any SAS data set.

The dataset I'm working with (.sas7bdat) is pretty large, with variable names that are just a string of random characters. Some of the columns have numeric entries and others have nonnumeric entries, but each column only has one or the other. Any recommendations on where to start? I can't figure out how to convert the dataset into an array such that I can check it column for column for numeric entries.

Comment: Hints: Get the data step to work for a single simple dataset, like SASHELP.CLASS, then think about how to generalize the code.  You can reference all of the numeric variables using a special syntax of a variable list.

Comment: You can reference all numeric variables with the `_numeric_` short cut. For example: `array myVars(*) _numeric_;`

Comment: functions that accept a variable number of arguments, such as the statistical functions, can accept a variable based array when it is specified as `of <arrayname>(*)`

Comment: This is a knowledge base, not a chat box. Please provide a title that will help others, having the same problem in the future, finding your question and our answers.

Comment: Your question title is not clarifying please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of all numerical variables and then find the mean and standard deviation of these using the syntax described here: https://support.sas.com/kb/41/380.html

If your input dataset is `sashelp.cars` then the code will be:

```
data want;
   set sashelp.class;

   array num_var(*) _numeric_;

   mean = mean(of num_var(*));
   std = std(of num_var(*));

   keep mean std;
run;
```